# Bracket operators inside here-document as argument?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

I saw a here-document used as an argument, which had square-bracket operators inside. It looked like:

```
method(<<EOF)[0][0]
lots of text
EOF
```

What might be the meaning of the square-bracket operators? Does anyone know what kind of idiom that is?

Comment: The square brackets aren't inside the heredoc, they're adjacent. `method()` returns an array of arrays and the bracket operators access the first element of the first array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that heredocs have a somewhat confusing structure that breaks the normal flow of code. The content of a heredoc begins on the line immediately after the `<<EOF` that opens the heredoc and ends at the `EOF` that closes the heredoc but the expression that contains the heredoc continues on from left to right as normal.

The structure of:

```
method(<<EOF)[0][0]
lots of text
EOF
```

is actually more like this:

```
      /<<EOF       \
      |lots of text|
      |lots of text|
method|lots of text|[0][0]
      |lots of text|
      |lots of text|
      \EOF         /
```

where the slashes and vertical bars are a crude attempt to draw very tall ASCII art parentheses; or, if you have a proper unicode font:

```
      ⎛<<EOF       ⎞
      ⎜lots of text⎟
      ⎜lots of text⎟
method⎜lots of text⎟[0][0]
      ⎜lots of text⎟
      ⎜lots of text⎟
      ⎝EOF         ⎠
```

You can think of heredocs as a funny looking double quote (or `%Q(...)` if you prefer) that goes vertically rather than horizontally like the rest of your code.

It would (IMO) be more consistent to write:

```
method(<<EOF
lots of text
EOF)[0][0]
```

but heredocs have a long history (going all the way back to `/bin/sh`) that we're stuck with.

Back to the real question: the `[0][0]` part of that expression isn't inside the heredoc at all, that's simply applied to what `method("lots of text\nlots of text\n...")` returns.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer !